# How to import a JSON file and use as a type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to import a JSON file with translated strings depending on the locale to use throughout a component in TSX.

```
import ComponentStrings from "../t9n/t9nComponentStrings.json";
```

In my TSConfig.json to do this, I turned on the following....

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

So I could import JSON files directly in Typescript.

However when I try to use it as a type like this....

```
  componentStrings: ComponentStrings = null;
```

I get this Typescript error...

```
'ComponentStrings' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ComponentStrings'?
```

How can I import the JSON file as a type and use it in my Typescript? To avoid making types for every single JSON translation file or using any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve the error using  typeof like...

```
  componentStrings: typeof ComponentStrings = null;
```

But not sure if there is a better way so I don't have to do this.

Comment: `ComponentStrings` is the object and `typeof ComponentStrings` is the type, so yes, this would be correct.